# React Router Loader is not getting called when component mounts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Very basic Loader function:

```
export async function loader({ params }) {
  console.log('loader function')
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(....request);
    console.log(response.data);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    throw new Error('Failed to load modal data.');
  }
}
```

My route definition is here:

```
export const App = () => {
  // ...other code

  return (
    <BrowserRouter basename={baseHref}>
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <Routes>
          <Route path={`/`} element={<App />}>
            <Route path={`Items`}>
              <Route path={`bill`} element={<XBill />}>
                <Route path=":billType/:modalId" element={<BillModal />} loader={loader} />
              </Route>
            </Route>
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </ErrorBoundary>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
```

In the case, my modal will pop up, which I assume means it did route to the `<BillModal>` component, but the loader is never called. I am very confused why this does not work. I expect the loader to be called since the component is mounted already. I think it might be `<BrowserRouter>`'s problem, however I am so sure why this could be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Loaders/actions](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/route/loader) only work in Data routers.

> ## Important
>
> This feature only works if using a data router, see [Picking a
> Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router)

See [Picking a Router](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/routers/picking-a-router) for details. Using them in regular routers will have no effect.

Update the code to use the Data APIs.

Example:

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  RouterProvider,
} from 'react-router-dom';

const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <App />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "Items",
        children: [
          {
            path: "bill",
            element: <XBill />,
            children: [
              {
                path: ":billType/:modalId",
                element: <BillModal />,
                loader,
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
], { basename: baseHref });

export const App = () => {
  // ...other code

  return (
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </ErrorBoundary>
  );
};
```